# Removing router from MySQL InnoDB cluster

Tags: mysql, linux, high-availability, mysql-innodb-cluster

Currently I have configured 3 node MYSQL InnoDB Cluster with two routers. Is it possible to remove one of the router from cluster? what are the implications ?
using cluster.listRouters() I could see two entries, is there a similar command to remove router.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A single router == a "single-point-of-failure".  That is, if it dies, the entire database is inaccessible.

(HA usually implies no single-point-of-failure.)